# Using AutoValue Annotations in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, auto-value

I'm porting an SDK from Android to plain Java and have run into an [AutoParcel](https://github.com/frankiesardo/auto-parcel) annotation that I don't understand.

Here's the [original class](https://github.com/pelias/pelias-android-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mapzen/pelias/SimpleFeature.java) and a snippet below:

```
@AutoParcel.Builder
public abstract static class Builder {
    public abstract Builder id(String id);
...
    public abstract SimpleFeature build();
}

public static Builder builder() {
    return new AutoParcel_SimpleFeature.Builder();
}
```

I am able to pretty much port everything to AutoValue without incident, except that last function, as I don't understand what it is or it's equivalent in AutoValue.

Can someone explain what this is, and what its equivalent is in AutoValue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JohnWowUs' comment suggests, this was largely an Eclipse issue.

The link he mentioned was only part of the solution, but I didn't need to drop more JARs into the project. With the help of an [issue in the AutoValue repo](https://github.com/google/auto/issues/106) and specifically configuring the maven-compiler-plugin, setting JDK1.7 as a target, with the following section added to the pom.xml:

```
<annotationProcessors>
    <annotationProcessor>com.google.auto.value.processor.AutoValueProcessor</annotationProcessor>
</annotationProcessors>
```

Answer (score 2):

The build annotation allows you to construct the immutable POJOs using the builder pattern i.e. something like

```
SimpleFeature.builder().id("test").build()
```

The equivalent annotation (not surprisingly since AutoParcel is a port of Autovalue with android specific features i.e. Parcelable)

```
@AutoValue.Builder
```

You should be able to find much more comprehensive documentation at https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value#builders

Comment: I tried that originally, but Eclipse suggests that the annotation is disallowed for this location.

Comment: Thank you for the response and pointers to the docs. Builder is a new, interesting pattern for me.
 I still see the error that AutoValue_SimpleFeature cannot be resolved to a type when creating the public static class. Eclipse wants to fill in all of the required functions from the abstract class, but that makes AutoValue worthless.

Comment: I think the problem is your eclipse settings. I don't use Eclipse myself but [this link](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/03/04/using-the-autovalue-code-generator-in-eclipse/) might help to get AutoValue and Eclipse working together.